# Getting textbox values inside table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html Table

```
<table id="tb">
<tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name </th>
  <th>Coutry</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="FName"/> </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="LName"/> </td>
   <td><input type="text" id="Country"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="FName"/> </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="LName"/> </td>
   <td><input type="text" id="Country"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
//Here I am looping through all the rows in table
$('#tb tr').each(function(i, row) {
  //Here I need to loop the tr again ( i.e. row) 
  $(row, "input").each(function(i, sr) {
    //here  I want to get all the textbox values
    alert($(sr).eq(0).val());
    alert($(sr).eq(1).val());
    alert($(sr).eq(2).val());
  });
});
```

But I am getting undefined values.

I want to get all the values from text boxes which are inside the table.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also, when/how do you execute your jQuery?

Comment: In button click event. I don't have control over ids as they are generated dynamically

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$('#tb tr').each(function(i, row) {
   $(this).find('input').each(function() {
     alert($(this).val())
   })
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$('#tb tr').each(function(i, row) {
   $(this).find('input').each(function() {
     alert($(this).val())
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Coutry</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="FName" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="LName" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Country" value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="FName" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="LName" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Country" value="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use :

```
$('#tb tr input[type=text]').each(function(){

  alert($(this).val());

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The line has the context switched with the selector

```
$(row, "input").each(function (i, sr) {
```

It should be

```
$("input", row).each(function (i, sr) {
```

or

```
$(row).find("input").each(function (i, sr) {
```